# How to do a rewrite in a premise?

Tags: agda

```
Any-comm : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} (xs ys : List A) →
           Any P (xs ++ ys) → Any P (ys ++ xs)
Any-comm xs [] prf = {!!}
```

```
Goal: Any P xs
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
prf : Any P (xs ++ [])
xs  : List A
P   : A → Set  (not in scope)
A   : Set  (not in scope)
```

How do I rewrite `prf` with the append identity here? I suppose I could rewrite the goal to match instead, but would it be possible to do the same in the premise? I feel the later would be more neat.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems my assumption of how rewrite works was wrong.

```
Any-comm xs [] prf rewrite sym (++-identityʳ xs) = {!!}
```

```
Goal: Any P (xs ++ [])
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
prf : Any P ((xs ++ []) ++ [])
P   : A → Set  (not in scope)
xs  : List A
A   : Set  (not in scope)
```

When I tried the above I was surprised to see it rewrite both the goal and the premise. So from that the way to rewrite the premise is.

```
Any-comm xs [] prf rewrite ++-identityʳ xs = prf
```

I am not sure if this is supposed to be so surprising, but I had not noticed this despite nearly going through the entirety of vol 1 of the PLFA book. This behavior is different from Coq's rewrite.